# scanf Output not showing of C language in kali terminal

Tags: c, terminal, scanf, kali-linux

I am currently doing C programming in the terminal of nano text editor in kali linux 2020.x.
15 minutes ago, I wrote a code which is not working finely. I am mentioning that code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int num;
  scanf("%d",&num);
  printf("number is %d",num);
  return 0;
}
```

I ran it. all things were ok, it compiled also, but when I am trying to enter value and press enter key, the output is blank/no output.

Comment: try adding a line feed to your output line. `"number is %d\n"`. Some terminal modes are line wise not character wise.

Comment: thanks , it works. very very thanks bro

Comment: you can also use `fflush(stdout)` after printf.

Comment: Note that you should check the return value from `scanf()` before using the value that may not have been assigned successfully.  Plan to end all printing operations with a newline; it helps ensure that the output appears timely when sent to a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have an answer yet, but I gave your question a shot and made this:

```
int main()
{

    int m_iValue = 0;
    
    scanf( "%i", &m_iValue );

    {
              char m_szBuffer[128]; // Note: We got a BIG buffer boy!
        sprintf( m_szBuffer, "Value: %i \n", m_iValue );

        printf( m_szBuffer );
    }

    return 0;

}
```

It works perfectly fine; hope it helps!

Comment: i will try it, after learning about sprintf function and %i format specifier. thanks for new aspect of my code.

Comment: Don't randomly guess at buffer sizes. This is how security flaws are born.